# How to rotate a square numpy array with different times efficiently by `np.rot90`?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, rotation

I have a 2d numpy array, for example:

```
a = np.array([
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]])
```

and another 1d array:

```
I = np.array([0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1])
```

I want to rotate `a` by `np.rot90` function like following:

```
b = np.zeros((len(I), 3, 3))
for i, k in enumerate(I):
    b[i] = np.rot90(a, k=k)
```

Can I do it more efficiently without the floop?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Yes, they work for me. Thanks very much.

Comment: Consider accepting one of those?

Comment: I like approach #2, because it has a good readability.

Comment: I meant accepting on one of the solutions by clicking on the green tick, as you did for your previous question to this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41789057/3293881

Comment: I am very sorry about it. I made a misunderstand. I had clicked the up triangle and I thought that meant I accepted your solution. Now I have clicked the green tick. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Generate a `3D` array of all possible `4` rotations and simply index into it with `I` and thus have a vectorized solution -

```
P = np.empty((4,) + a.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
P[0] = a            # For np.rot90(a, k=0)
P[1] = a.T[::-1]    # For np.rot90(a, k=1)
P[2] = a[::-1,::-1] # For np.rot90(a, k=2)
P[3] = a.T[:,::-1]  # For np.rot90(a, k=3)
out = P[I]
```

**Approach #2**

Another way to create `P` would be with -

```
P = np.array([np.rot90(a, k=i) for i in range(4)])
```

and as with the previous method simply index into `P` with `I` for final output.

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def org_app(a, I):
    m,n = a.shape
    b = np.zeros((len(I), m, n), dtype=a.dtype)
    for i, k in enumerate(I):
        b[i] = np.rot90(a, k=k)
    return b

def app1(a, I):
    P = np.empty((4,) + a.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
    P[0] = a  
    P[1] = a.T[::-1]
    P[2] = a[::-1,::-1]
    P[3] = a.T[:,::-1]
    return P[I]

def app2(a, I):
    P = np.array([np.rot90(a, k=i) for i in range(4)])
    return P[I]
```

Timings -

```
In [54]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(10,10))

In [55]: I = np.random.randint(0,4,(10000))

In [56]: %timeit org_app(a, I)
10 loops, best of 3: 51 ms per loop

In [57]: %timeit app1(a, I)
1000 loops, best of 3: 469 µs per loop

In [58]: %timeit app2(a, I)
1000 loops, best of 3: 549 µs per loop
```

**`100x+`** speedup!

Answer (score 0):

One more efficient way that I can think of (still not vectorized) is using a list comprehension, in one line:

```
np.array([np.rot90(a, k=i) for i in I])
```